# Rails 3 - How to set different id (html attribute) in nested form attributes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm developing a rails 3.0.9 app, I'm using "accept nested attributes
for" to add dynamically new "child" items to its "parentW. the thing is
every child has the same id (html attribute), and I need every child with its own id,
because I need to make some jquery functions to work with them.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Tanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an new element to a Nested Form was handled brilliantly in a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2). In it, Ryan uses javascript to replace the ID attribute with something more meaningful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It was my fault, I was doing something wrong, but I already solve it... Thanks